# Extract text between two specific lines

Tags: text-processing

How can I get the part of the output of a command between two specific lines? A dummy example:

Command:

```
git for-each-ref --sort='*authordate' --format='%(tag)' refs/tags | grep -v '^$'
```

Output:

```
0.1.0
0.2.0
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.1.0
1.2.0
1.2.1
1.3.0
1.4.0
1.4.1
```

I want to get the part of this output, between two specific lines (not based on line number, based on content):

```
0.1.0
0.2.0
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pipe output to `awk`:

```
$ ... | awk '/0\.1\.0/,/1\.0\.2/'
0.1.0
0.2.0
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need, works as expected. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

you can pipe it to `sed`:

```
.... | sed -n "/0.1.0/,/1.0.2/p" YourFile
```